# Speed up loop for matplotlib in python

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I have a similar, but larger data set with more dates and over ten thousand rows. Usually, it takes 3mins or longer to run the code and plot. I think the problem comes from loop. Looping is time-consuming in python. In this case, would be appreciated if someone knows how to rewrite the code to make it faster.

```
  data = {'Date' : ["2022-07-01"]*5000 + ["2022-07-02"]*5000+ ["2022-07-03"]*5000,        
          'OB1' : range(1,15001),
          'OB2' : range(1,15001)}

  df = pd.DataFrame(data)      

  # multi-indexing
  df = df.set_index(['Date'])

  # loop for plot
  i = 1
  fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3, sharey = True)
  fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0) 
  for j, sub_df in df.groupby(level=0):
      plt.subplot(130 + i)
      x = sub_df['OB1']
      y = sub_df['OB2']
      plt.barh(x, y) 
      i = i + 1
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowness comes from the `barh` function, which involves drawing many rectangles. While your example is already pretty slow (a minute on my laptop), this one runs in less than a second. I replaced `barh` with `fill_betweenx`, which fills the area between two curves (here 0 and the height of bars) instead of drawing rectangles. It goes much faster but is not strictly the same. Also, I use the option `step=post`, so if you zoom, you will have a bar-style graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    "Date": ["2022-07-01"] * 5000
    + ["2022-07-02"] * 5000
    + ["2022-07-03"] * 5000,
    "OB1": range(1, 15001),
    "OB2": range(1, 15001),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# multi-indexing
df = df.set_index(["Date"])

# loop for plot
i = 1
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
for j, sub_df in df.groupby(level=0):
    plt.subplot(130 + i)
    x = sub_df["OB1"]
    y = sub_df["OB2"]
    # plt.barh(x, y)
    plt.fill_betweenx(y, 0, x, step="post")
    i = i + 1
plt.show()
```

[image: barh made with filll_betweenx]